# AppEngine - Optimize read/write count on POST request

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I need to optimize the read/write count for a POST request that I'm using.

Some info about the request:

- The user sends a JSON array of ~100 items
- The servlet needs to check if any of the received items is newer then its counterpart in the datastore using a single `long` attribute
- I'm using JDO

what i currently do is (pseudo code):

```
 foreach(item : json.items) {
     storedItem = persistenceManager.getObjectById(item.key);
     if(item.long > storedItem.long) {
         // Update storedItem
     }
 }
```

Which obviously results in ~100 read requests per request.

What is the best way to reduce the read count for this logic? Using JDO `Query`? I read that using "IN"-Queries simply results in multiple queries executed after another, so I don't think that would help me :(

There also is `PersistenceManager.getObjectsById(Collection)`. Does that help in any way? Can't find any documentation of how many requests this will issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use below call to do a batch get:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery("select from " + Content.class.getName() + " where contentKey == :contentKeys");
```

Something like above query would return all objects you need. 
And you can handle all the rest from here.

Comment: Obviously that is not the "low-level API" you quote there

Comment: just checked with appstats tool and this results in ONE datastored get call :)

Comment: Yep, I think @DataNucleus is right. I always thought that way... Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is

```
pm.getObjectsById(ids);
```

since that is intended for getting multiple objects in a call (particularly since you have the ids, hence keys). Certainly current code (2.0.1 and later) ought to do a single datastore call for getEntities(). See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=197&can=1&q=label%3aTargetRelease-2.0.1&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20FoundIn%20TargetRelease%20Owner%20Summary)

Comment: what does this getObjectsById call actcually do? Does it do a batch get or does it do getObjectById for each id?

Comment: "Certainly current code (2.0.1 and later) ought to do a single datastore call for getEntities()". Obviously you could easily read the log to confirm such things